# How to get clone source Id for the records coming from database

Tags: apex, sobject, salesforce-id, clone

```
Account acc0 = new account(name="acme");
Insert acc;
Account acc1 = acc0.clone();
insert acc1;
System.debug(acc1.getCloneSourceId()); //Producing expected result as the record(Acc1) is in runtime memory
Account acc2 = [select id from account where id =: acc1.id];
system.debug(acc2.getCloneSourceId());//Is producing null value, as the record is retrieved from database
```

**How to get the Clone Id of a record coming from the database?**

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible. You will need to think of an approach to use custom fields/triggers to keep track of clones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom field where you can store the Source Record ID and an optional checkbox to mark the record as cloned.

Here is way to do that:

Just write a before trigger on Object like this:

```
trigger ARecordTrigger on ARecord__c (before insert) {

    List<ARecord__c> lstARecords = (List<ARecord__c>) Trigger.new;

    if(lstARecords.get(0).isClone()){
        lstARecords.get(0).ClonedSourceID__c = lstARecords.get(0).getCloneSourceId();
    }

}
```

`ClonedSourceID__c` is a custom field created in `ARecord__c` object.

**NOTE: Not bulkified. Edit and bulkify it when writing your logic**

As this is a custom field, you can query `ClonedSourceID__c` anytime you want and you will get the record id from where the record was cloned.